# How to access current actual class from static Main method

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, static-methods

I want to create an abstract class with a main method, to prevent developers who extend it from having to implement the main method. I also want to control what happens in the main method.

The abstract base class that I'm writing extends `NanoHTTPD`, and you start the server by calling `ServerRunner.run()` with the parameter being a class object of the type of the class that you want to run.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public abstract class FlexibleServer extends NanoHTTPD
{
    public DeadSimpleMicroserver(int port)
    {
        super(port);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ServerRunner.run(FlexibleServer.class);
    }
}
```

The problem is that since this class is abstract, future developers will be extending the class, so I need the parameter to `ServerRunner.run()` to be the ACTUAL type of the subclass, so I can't use `FlexibleServer.class`.

I tried changing the parameter to this.class, but then I get the compile error that "this" cannot be referenced from a static context (because `main()` is static).

How can get a class object of the actual subclass from `main()`?

Answer (score 1):

If the class that you're going to pass at runtime is dynamic, then you cannot call it with a hard-coded class name. You will have to change your call to `run` so that you pass it either an instance of the actual class, or you would have to dynamically load the class given, for example, main method arguments.

With the above change, your problem gets resolved.

For example, if you're loading the class dynamically:

```
ServerRunner.run(Class.forName(args[0]));
```

Assuming the app will be called with the actual class name.

Alternatives include redesigning your code such that either a class name, an instance, or class object is passed in by the caller

Answer (score 0):

A framework I once worked on had a base class like this, and we added a method like this:

```
public abstract class FrameworkServer {
    // framework stuff

    protected static void main(String[] args, FrameworkServer instance) {
        // parse args
        // actually start the instance running
    }
}
```

And a specific server instance would need to add its own `main` method like so:

```
final class MyServer extends FrameworkServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main(args, new MyServer());
    }
 }
```

There is a small bit of boilerplate here for each server, but that allows you do avoid reflection and to make the code much clearer. As a bonus, the concrete subclasses can now add their own arguments to their server's constructor, which is often very useful for unit-testing.